# determine whether body's background-image (css) has been loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, image

Depending on some conditions, different background images are loaded:

```
$('body').css('background','url(image.png)');
```

Is there a way to determine whether the background image has loaded? I need to execute a function when the image has been loaded.

Comment: You could possibly add an `Image` element with `src="image.png"` and attach an `onLoad` handler. The browser will only load the image once so if the `Image` element is created before the `background-image` property is set you should be able to use the `onLoad` handler. Untested, though :(

Comment: The already posted answers may work correctly for most cases, but beware that the images' `load` event has some caveats. [Read this](http://api.jquery.com/load-event/) (scroll down to the `Caveats of the load event when used with images` part).

Comment: @FabrícioMatté the caveats are pretty disturbing. However I am using the native onload, i.e. `img.onload = function(){}` Is that safer to use than jQuery's `.load()`?

Comment: The `onload` HTML attribute is `eval`uated to a JS property, slightly different than jQuery `.load()` which attaches a `load` event handler. In the end of the day, both do pretty much the same, except that the jQuery devs (most often) try to solve compatibility issues better than just attaching a native event handler. Well, from experience, I've used the `.load()` handler for images a couple times and didn't see any issue, just leaving that reference so you will know about it in case an issue ever arises. `=]`

Comment: ^ And by `both do pretty much the same` I mean in functionality (both fire in the `load` event) but obviously an element can only have one `onload` attribute/`load` property while it allows having multiple `.load()` event handlers, but that's a slightly different topic.

Comment: Here's the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yrYLc/) to illustrate all that I said. `;)`

Comment: Using codebox's code should do fine, as long as you set the `onload` handler before the `src` in a dynamically created element it fires consistently in all browsers I've tested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could load the image into a hidden `<img>` tag and assign an `onload` handler to the tag. In the onload handler you could populate the background image of the body (which should happen more or less instantly because the image is now in the browser cache) and then run your custom code as well.

```
var hiddenImg = new Image();
hiddenImg.onload = function(){
    $('body').css('background','url(' + this.src + ')');
    your_custom_onload_code();
};
hiddenImg.src = 'image.png';
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var img = new Image ();
img.onload = function () { $('body').css('background','url(image.png)'); };
img.src = src;
```